# Tool to view previous jmeter results

Tags: ant, jmeter, performance-testing, bamboo

We are using Jmeter and Ant for performance testing and Bamboo for Continuous Integration but due to incompatibility of Jmeter Aggregator Plugin we are unable to view previous results. What alternatives can we use?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an external file to save the results to. Any type of results in JMeter can be written to and saved in an external file. Then you can review those files anytime you want.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter Aggregator plugin was just marked as compatible with latest version of Bamboo 6.9.2. Please check if it works for you: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/5902/jmeter-aggregator-for-bamboo?hosting=server&tab=overview